# OpenSSL 1.0.2 and error "SSL_CTX_new:library has no ciphers"

Tags: c, windows, openssl

I am attempting to compile and run an example from [libest](https://github.com/cisco/libest) (client-simple). To do that, I compiled OpenSSL on windows, and then compiled and linked libest with that.

The problem is that when I run the program, I get `error:140A90A1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:library has no ciphers`:

[image]

Looking at the code in the debugger, I can confirm that `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf` gets called, as well as:

- `ERR_load_crypto_strings()`
- `ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();`
- `SSL_library_init();`
- `SSL_load_error_strings();`

What might be missing/need to be configured to allow OpenSSL to find the cipher suites? If I run the `openSSL.exe` that I built at the same time as the .lib and .dll for openSSL, it lists many many ciphers.

The actual call that is causing the error is `SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()))`. But it does not change if I change the client method.

Why am I encountering the error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the order of the calls you listed. Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use TLS 1.1 or above. You probably also need Server Name Indication (SNI). SNI is enlisted with `-servername` below.

We need to see more of the code to tell you where the problem is/are. In the meantime, you might want to visit [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. (It looks like the site is going through some maintenance at the moment. Here's an archived versionfrom [the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629145724/http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client)).

***TLS 1.2***:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect testrfc7030.cisco.com:9443 -servername testrfc7030.cisco.com -tls1_2
...
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: B04740547F80E8F8BFC1B966D28C861F590E7ABB31202E2ED343EFDBA1A08867
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C6EF3571832C482E1293E78B0410E544140182858A91DDE16FD32CF248D442673C47C902A560A541B1D6C417E35DF804
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1478031623
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
```

***TLS 1.1***:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect testrfc7030.cisco.com:9443 -servername testrfc7030.cisco.com -tls1_1
...
New, SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 62324F8BE5178E801F76B4737DD9F711AC0072E885B8748BB5B8F3ED3D16C8DE
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 4E44928C5E395E80AEF02533DAA0D237C58B5153CCCA16150B2DEDE361043BFB69D534F52A203084871F1683BDB241EF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1478031773
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
```

***TLS 1.0***:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect testrfc7030.cisco.com:9443 -servername testrfc7030.cisco.com -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
...
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1478031817
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with my tcp client.
So, I found a code in github to try and run it to check if I was getting the same errors.

The repo link: [SSL TCP-Server](https://github.com/Lalbadshah/TCP-Connection-using-OPENSSL/blob/master/PROJ_server.c#L135)

After that I introduced a line in my code:

`$ SSL_library_init();`

This line solved my problem. 
You can find my code here:
[TCP Client-Server with Open SSL](https://github.com/iammainul/microSec_Internship/tree/master/week-1)